# How to to use require.js and optimizer to build a library

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm thinking about using require.js and it's optimzier to combine and minify a library that consists of more then one js-file. Every js-file contains one single module. But there is no main-module that requires (imports) all modules/js-files.
I want to combine all files in one file, that could be used as a library. In that way I could ship the library in one single file instead of several files.

Is this possible, or do I have to create some kind of a main-module that requires /imports all  other modules?

Thanks for your help!

treeno

Answer (score 2):

I've not tried it myself but you should be able to pass a build configuration to `r.js` that contains the following:

```
modules: [{
    name: "my-lib.js",
    create: true,
    include: ["moduleA", "moduleB", ...]
}]
```

This tells `r.js` to put into a single file named `my-lib.js` all of the dependencies listed in `include` and tells it that there is no corresponding file named `my-lib.js` in your *sources* but that `r.js` should create it in the *output*. So the key is:

- List all the modules you want in `include`.
- Use `create: true`.

The documentation on the optimizer does not mention `create` but you can find it documented [here](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js).

Comment: Sorry, for my late response. I dind't find the time to go on with this problem yet. But thanks for your help so far!